# Are there instances when scripture associates the deeds of one avatar with another avatar?

Tags: avatars

Each avatar performs specific deeds.  Rama killed Ravana, built the bridge etc.  Krishna plays the flute, did the Kaliya dance and so forth.

Does scripture ever praise one avatar by citing the deeds of another?

Answer (score 0):

Tulsi das transfers the praise that is due to Vamana (whose feet are said to release the Ganga from Satyaloka in some puranas ) to Rama.

https://rasikas.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=15544

ram charan sukhadayi - tulsidas bhajan

> jin caranan se nikalIn surasari shankar jaTA samAyI
> jaTA shankarI nAm paDyo hai tribhuvan tAran AyI

> From (se) which (jin) feet (caranan) emanated (nikalI) the river of gods (surasarI - ganga) and immersed (samAI) in the matted locks (jaTA) of Lord Shiva. Since then, she was named (nAm paDyO) jaTA ShankarI and she came (AyI) for the redemption (tAran) of the three worlds (tribhuvan).

Comment: This is not transferring praise. Here Tulsidas is talking about Rama as Supreme god. So he is saying that Rama as Vamana released Ganga.